# Downgrade SQL Server 2014 SP1 to SQL Server 2014 (without service pack)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Has anyone successfully downgraded a specific database from SQL Server 2014 SP1 (12.0.4XXX) to SQL Server 2014 without service packs (12.0.2000)?

If so, would love to be pointed to any useful solutions not involving a larger uninstall/reinstall/restore of the overall server.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't downgrade a SQL Server Instance. You would need to create a new instance, and `RESTORE` your databases onto the new Instance (apart from the System Databases, which you would need to script out for.). *As a point of interest, **why** do you want to downgrade?*

Comment: I'm with @Larnu on this one. Removing a service pack seems like a really bad idea. What could you possibly hope to gain from this? Thankfully it is not possible.

Comment: @lamu -- Thanks for your comments, let me clarify: I'm not trying to downgrade the _instance_ -- just a single database attached to instance. The reason for the downgrade is transferring to another sever (not internal, external to my firm) that does not have SP1 installed -- thus they cannot attach an SP1-created database

Comment: @larnu -- see above comment, got the username wrong before.

Comment: Normally you **can** restore databases cross service pack (apart from system databases). Have you given it a try? I'm not aware that 2014 SP1 is an exception. @SeanLange have you heard that this is the case?

Comment: @Larnu I have not heard anything to contradict that. OP - perhaps you should convince the other location that it is time to install their service pack. :)

Comment: SP1 for 2014 came out in 2015, so it would seem that "the time has come". Unless they have a specific reason you could share?